# Angular 12 error 401 when page is refreshed

Tags: angular, frontend

I am doing a login form using angular 12 + Spring boot(w/ basic authentication spring security). When the user logs in they will be redirected to the main page which has CRUD actions as seen below:

[image: login]
[image: main page]

But, when page is refreshed or reload it goes back to this (observe the console, it returns a 401 unauthorized status even if I already logged in):

[image: error_console]

Here is my code from Angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser';

  public username: String = '';
  public password: String = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  authenticationService(username: String, password: String) {
    return this.http
      .get(`http://localhost:8081/webapp/login/`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password),
        },
      })
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          this.username = username;
          this.password = password;
          this.registerSuccessfulLogin(username, password);
        })
      );
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username: any, password: String) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    if (user === null) return false;
    return true;
  }

}
```

Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHeaders,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpinterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser';

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthService) {}
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (
      this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() &&
      req.url.indexOf('basicauth') === -1
    ) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Basic ${window.btoa(
            this.authenticationService.username +
              ':' +
              this.authenticationService.password
          )}`,
        }),
      });
      return next.handle(authReq);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `AuthService`.

1. You are not storing password anywhere when the user is successfully logged in.
2. And then when you go on to refresh this page your `isUserLoggedIn` only finds `username` in session storage [**Plus you are not updating both `username and password` in `AuthService`**].

The `intercepter` thus, does not find any`username` or `password` in `this.authenticationService.username/password`

```
 createBasicAuthToken(username: String, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
  }

  registerSuccessfulLogin(username: any, password: String) {
    // HERE ONLY username is stored
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    // HERE username and password for this service should be updated.
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    if (user === null) return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Somehow storing these should work for you, whether you want to store password simpy or in encrypted format is your choice.

Comment: I tried placing the username and password, rather, I encrypted them using basic authentication. Check my answer below this. Still, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

Problem: When page is reloaded/refreshed after logging/signing-in data is lost and throws a status 401 unauthorized.

Cause: Credentials is not saved in session when logged in, thus, refreshing page loses the credentials upon logging in

Solution:

In `AuthenticationService`, revise the `registerSuccessfulLogin()` by adding this in the body:

```
  registerSuccessfulLogin(username: any, password: String) {
    let basicAuthToken = this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password);
    sessionStorage.setItem(
      this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
      basicAuthToken
    );
  }
```

What was added?

`let basicAuthToken = this.createBasicAuthToken(username, password);`

This assigns the return value of `createBasicAuthToken(username, password)` method which returns a 'Basic : xxxxxxx' basic64 encoded string. Why would you include both credentials in encoding? Because my mistake was I was only encoding the username, instead both of the credentials(which also include the password). In `sessionStorage.setItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,basicAuthToken);` the value stored now has both username and password encrypted in base64(not just the username, compared to the previous version).

Also, in the `AuthenticationService` class include the following method:

```
  getIt() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
  }
```

Wait, was is this method for? It retrieves the saved data from the sessionStorage. You will be needing this when we inject the class in the interceptor class.

Next, the interceptor class. The following are the changes made from the previous:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class HttpinterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthService,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    if (
      this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn() &&
      req.url.indexOf('basicauth') === -1
    ) {
      const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `${authService.getIt()}`,
        }),
      });
      return next.handle(authReq);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    console.log(this.intercept);
  }
}
```

First, import the Injector class, this will be used in a while.

```
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthService,private injector: Injector)
```

By injecting the AuthenticationService and Injector services we can now access the methods that we will be using in our interceptors.

```
let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
```

This line assigns the `authService` variable to the instance based on the provided token (`AuthService`).

```
Authorization: `${authService.getIt()}`
```

Now, we can use the variable containing the token instance in the authorization using the code above in which call the `getIt()` from our `AuthenticationService` class that returns the encrypted credentials.

In this way, every time we refresh after logging in the credential are stored in session and are checked every time a page is loaded and/or reloaded. The credentials will only be valid until server or frontend services is terminated or when browser or tab is closed.