# Angular 12 : after login if reload page getting 401

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, token, access-token

In angular project, after successful login getting `401 - Unauthorized`  or `401 - "Invalid user"` after some time or when reloading any page.

**AuthInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            const authToken = this.authService.getAuthorizationToken();
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders:
                    { Authorization: authToken }
                }
            );
        }
        
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

**AuthService functions**

```
  login(email: string, password: string) {
        let input = new FormData();
        const headers = { 'APP-TOKEN': 'some' }
        input.append("email", email);
        input.append("password", password);
        return this.http.post<any>(`${this.serverUrl}api/v1/login`, input, { 'headers': headers })
          .pipe(map(user => {
            if (user && user.token) {
              localStorage.setItem('demoUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    
            }
            return user;
          }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
      }
    
      isLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('demoUser')) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
  getAuthorizationToken() {
    const myUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('demoUser'));
    // return myUser.token;
    if (myUser.token)
      return myUser.token;
    else
      return null;
  }
```

Calling API like below

```
 getActiveUserDetails(id) {
    let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('demoUser'));
    const headers = { 'Authorization': userDetails.token }

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.myapiURL}api/v1/getActiveUserDetails`, {id }, { 'headers': headers })
      .pipe(map(response => {
        return response;
      }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

I searched for it but not getting where I need to check and change. I think, Api's somehow not getting valid token on reload or after some time, its not matching I guess though its available in storage and also checked token in request headers on inspect, its present.
I got relevant case[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188124/angular-12-error-401-when-page-is-refreshed). But seems same way in my code also.

How should I solve this issue? Please help and guide.

**NOTE:** I am getting token from api(backend - laravel(JWT)) in format 'Bearer + token'. And from backend there is no expiry time limit set.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the string 'Bearer ' in the interceptor

```
  { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken }
```

and you can remove this code and send post without header in your service (use only header of interceptor):

```
 let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('demoUser'));
    const headers = { 'Authorization': userDetails.token }
```

for more information check this link: https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-refresh-token/

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I am getting token with string 'Bearer ' from api and storing that so I am not adding that in headers

Comment: You are welcome, Good job :)

Comment: Actually what i was telling that I does not need to add  string 'Bearer '  like you said, as I am getting token from api (backend) with string 'Bearer ' attatched. I already has that in my token